# getQualificationScore returning "QualificationType does not Exist" for Base Qualifications Type (approval rate, etc)

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I've got a bunch of results from a Mechanical Turk HIT that I had done, and I want to try and rank all my answers by how trustworthy that Worker was. To do that, I'm trying to get each submitting worker's accept rate from MTurk.

I do this using the [MTurk API QualificationRequirement](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/2007-06-21/ApiReference_QualificationRequirementDataStructureArticle.html) type, "Worker_PercentAssignmentsApproved", whose type_id is 000000000000000000L0.

To get the worker's rating for percent approved, I call [GetQualificationScore](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/index.html?ApiReference_GetQualificationScoreOperation.html), which returns to me this very angry message:

```
 <GetQualificationScoreResponse>
   <OperationRequest>
     <RequestId>e5a68cbf-f8a4-4fc6-8d47-8198a138fe12</RequestId>
   </OperationRequest>
   <Qualification>
     <Request>
       <IsValid>False</IsValid>
       <Errors>
         <Error>
           <Code>AWS.MechanicalTurk.QualificationTypeDoesNotExist</Code>
           <Message>
             QualificationType 000000000000000000L0 does not exist (1287717938474) 
           </Message>
         </Error>
       </Errors>
     </Request>
   </Qualification>
 </GetQualificationScoreResponse>
```

Perhaps I had some formatting issues and was calling the method wrong.

To test that, I called [GetQualificationType](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/index.html?ApiReference_GetQualificationTypeOperation.html) (which takes the same type of argument for the type: (QualificationTypeId, The ID of the Qualification type, String)).

Here's the thing: that works perfectly.

**So, here's my question:** Does Amazon just not permit access to base qualification/stats  about workers that have done HITs for requesters? Or is there a way to get at this data that I haven't thought of?

**Note** I'm using a slightly-modified version of boto to make these calls, but have found boto to be buggy/lacking for this particular stuff. At this point I'm +/- working on the XML call level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Correct, you can't query a Worker's
>   system Qualifications directly.  You
>   can create HITs with Qualification
>   requirements based on system
>   Qualifications, but that's it.
>
> Currently, the only way to gather
>   specific data about a Worker is to
>   analyze your own results for HITs and
>   Qualification tests.  You can store
>   the results of your own analysis in
>   Quals you create yourself and update
>   them over time, and use those Quals as
>   the basis for Qual requirements for
>   your HITs.your HITs.

-DAN@AWS, Amazon, [responding to this question](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=46629) back in 2006.

So, it looks like this can't be done directly.  Sadface.